# Display time datatype as AM/PM time in DataList

Tags: c#, datetime, data-binding, datalist, timespan

```
<asp:Label ID="timeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("time") %>' />
```

In this statement, "time" is a time datatype in my database. It displays as 16:00:00. I am trying to get this to display as 4:00 PM. I think this is pretty straight forward if I were working with a datetime datatype, but how can I convert this to datetime (to use the {HH.mm tt} formatting) or otherwise display with as AM/PM time.

Answer (score 1):

Since T-SQL [`time`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) is mapped with [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.timespan.aspx) in CLR side, when you get this value from your database, it will be `TimeSpan`, not a `DateTime`.

And you can't represent a `TimeSpan` with `AM` or `PM` designators. These are only for `DateTime` representations. There is no such a thing a `TimeSpan` like; *4 hour time interval afternoon*. That doesn't make sense, right?

Closest thing *might* be, getting this value from your database and add it to your [`DateTime.Today`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value with [`Add(TimeSpan)` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload. Then you can get it's string representation with `.ToString("h:mm tt")` method with a culture that doesn't have `AMDesignator` and `PMDesignator` as an empty string.

Step by step;

1. Get your `time` as a `TimeSpan` from your database.
2. Get a DateTime with `DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.Add(time)` method.
3. Show it's string representation with `dt.ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: Could you add the time to an arbitrary date without a time component (e.g. `DateTime.Today`) and then format it, using only time components (e.g. `hh:mm tt`)?

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Updating the same idea while you wrote your comment. That's the closest things to get it IMO. Also I think `h` would be better since looks like OP doesn't have a leading zero for single digits.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this one with SQL instead of C# here.
I did try to add the TimeSpan to a DateTime within the Eval() argument, but I kept getting a FormatException. Also, the expression was getting kind of ridiculous.

I tried this

```
<asp:Label ID="timeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# DateTime.Today.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(Eval("time").ToString())).ToString("h:mm tt") %>' />
```

and this

```
<asp:Label ID="timeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval(DateTime.Today.Add(TimeSpan.Parse("time")).ToString("h:mm tt")) %>' />
```

It was considerably easier to modify the query to use

```
SELECT  CONVERT(varchar, [time], 100 ) AS [time]
```

I am happy with this result. Though, I would be curious to know if I was on the right track with the C# expressions. Thanks so much for the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%#DateTime.Today.Add((TimeSpan)(Eval("Event_From_Time"))).ToString("H:mm tt")%>
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are frowned upon on SO.